# Getting odd character when converting an integer to byte array

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using the following snippet to convert integers to a `vector<unsigned char>`:

```
const vector<unsigned char> int_to_bytearray(const size_t value) noexcept {
      unsigned char bytes[4];
      bytes[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
      bytes[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
      bytes[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
      bytes[3] = value & 0xFF;
      const vector<unsigned char>to_return(bytes, bytes + sizeof bytes);
      return to_return;
}
```

If I pass the value `196608` I get `{'\x00', '\x03', '\x00', '\x00'}` which is what I expect. If I pass `37` I get `{ 0, 0, 0, % }` and the percentage mark is throwing me off. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you inspecting the result?

Comment: % is what 37 is as a character in ASCII.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting the '%' character, which has the code 37. So everything is working as expected.